# In react-native scrollToOffset in flat list is not working properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In flatlist scroll to offset is not working properly when the no of items are less than 3. If the no of items are greater or equal to 3 than it is working exactly fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Animated, Dimensions, RefreshControl, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { HEADER_HEIGHT } from '.'
import { CustomText, FlatListWrapper, FlatListWrapperProps } from '../../../common-library/components'
import { ScrollValueContext } from './Context'
import { get } from 'lodash'
import { CENTER, colors, dimens, ROW, SPACE_BETWEEN } from '../../../common-library/config'
import { TAB_BAR_HEIGHT } from './CommunityHeaderComponent'
import { IconButtonWrapper } from '../generic'
import { icons } from '../../common'
import { log } from '../../config'

const labels = {
    GO_TO_TOP: 'Go to Top'
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contentStyle: {
        paddingTop: HEADER_HEIGHT
    },
    scrollToTopContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: TAB_BAR_HEIGHT,
        alignItems: 'center',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        zIndex: 999
    },
    buttonsContainer: {
        borderColor: colors.DuckBlue,
        backgroundColor: colors.DuckBlue,
        borderRadius: dimens.size25,
        width: 110,
        flexDirection: ROW,
        justifyContent: SPACE_BETWEEN,
        paddingVertical: dimens.size10,
        alignItems: CENTER
    },
    buttonCta: {
        paddingLeft: dimens.size15
    },
    goToTopLabel: {
        color: colors.White,
        textAlign: CENTER
    },
    crossIconCta: {
        justifyContent: CENTER,
        alignItems: CENTER,
        paddingRight: dimens.size15
        // paddingTop: dimens.size2
    }
})

interface State {
    shouldRefresh?: boolean
    showScrollToTopView?: boolean
    dontShowGoToTop?: boolean
}

interface Props extends FlatListWrapperProps {
    uniqueKey?: string
    getFlatListRef?: (ref) => any
    getScrolledPosition?: (contentOffset) => any
    onPullToRefresh?: () => any
    renderScrollToTopView?: boolean
}

export class StickyScrollableFlatlistComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
    flatListRef
    scrolledValue
    timerRef
    state = {
        shouldRefresh: false,
        showScrollToTopView: false,
        dontShowGoToTop: false
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { showScrollToTopView, dontShowGoToTop } = this.state
        if ((!prevProps.isFetching && this.props.isFetching) || (prevProps.isFetching && !this.props.isFetching)) {
            if ((showScrollToTopView || dontShowGoToTop) && this.props.renderScrollToTopView) {
                this.setState({
                    showScrollToTopView: false,
                    dontShowGoToTop: false
                })
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                log('setTileout is called', this.scrolledValue > HEADER_HEIGHT, this.scrolledValue)
                this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({
                    offset: this.scrolledValue > HEADER_HEIGHT ? HEADER_HEIGHT : HEADER_HEIGHT,
                    animated: false
                })
            }, 2000)
        }
    }

    onRefresh = () => {
        const { onPullToRefresh } = this.props
        if (onPullToRefresh) {
            this.setState({
                shouldRefresh: true
            })
            onPullToRefresh().then(() => {
                this.setState({
                    shouldRefresh: false
                })
            })
        }
    }

    showScrollToTopView = () => {
        const { showScrollToTopView } = this.state
        const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height
        if (this.scrolledValue >= 2 * DEVICE_HEIGHT - HEADER_HEIGHT && !showScrollToTopView) {
            this.setState({
                showScrollToTopView: true
            })
        } else if (this.scrolledValue <= DEVICE_HEIGHT - HEADER_HEIGHT && showScrollToTopView) {
            this.setState({
                showScrollToTopView: false
            })
        }
    }

    onClikCrossIcon = () => {
        this.setState({
            dontShowGoToTop: true,
            showScrollToTopView: false
        })
    }

    moveToTop = () => {
        this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({
            offset: HEADER_HEIGHT,
            animated: true
        })
    }

    renderScrollToTopView = () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.scrollToTopContainer}>
                <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.moveToTop} style={styles.buttonCta} activeOpacity={1}>
                        <CustomText textStyle={styles.goToTopLabel}>{labels.GO_TO_TOP}</CustomText>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClikCrossIcon} style={styles.crossIconCta} activeOpacity={1}>
                        <IconButtonWrapper iconImage={icons.CROSSWHITE_ICON} iconHeight={dimens.size10} iconWidth={dimens.size10} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { shouldRefresh, showScrollToTopView, dontShowGoToTop } = this.state
        const { getFlatListRef, uniqueKey, getScrolledPosition, renderScrollToTopView = false } = this.props
        return (
            <ScrollValueContext.Consumer>
                {(context) => (
                    <>
                        {showScrollToTopView && !dontShowGoToTop && renderScrollToTopView && this.renderScrollToTopView()}
                        <FlatListWrapper
                            {...this.props}
                            onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: context.scrollYValue } } }], {
                                useNativeDriver: true,
                                listener: ({ nativeEvent }) => {
                                    const yOffsetValue = get(nativeEvent, 'contentOffset.y', 0)
                                    log('Flatlist wrapper on event is called', yOffsetValue)
                                    this.scrolledValue = yOffsetValue
                                    // context.scrollYValue.setValue(this.scrolledValue)
                                    {
                                        renderScrollToTopView && this.showScrollToTopView()
                                    }
                                    if (getScrolledPosition) {
                                        getScrolledPosition(yOffsetValue)
                                    }
                                }
                            })}
                            refreshControl={
                                <RefreshControl
                                    refreshing={shouldRefresh}
                                    progressViewOffset={HEADER_HEIGHT}
                                    onRefresh={() => {
                                        this.onRefresh()
                                    }}
                                />
                            }
                            showCustomizedAnimatedFlatList={true}
                            contentContainerStyle={[styles.contentStyle, this.props.contentContainerStyle]}
                            scrollEventThrottle={16}
                            inputRef={(ref) => {
                                log('inputRefinputRefis called')
                                if (ref) {
                                    this.flatListRef = ref
                                    if (getFlatListRef) {
                                        getFlatListRef(ref)
                                    }
                                    context.addFlatListRef(this.flatListRef, uniqueKey)
                                }
                            }}
                            onMomentumScrollEnd={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                                const { contentOffset } = nativeEvent
                                if (contentOffset.y === 0) {
                                    log('inside onMomentumScrollEnd')
                                    context.flatListRef.forEach((item) => {
                                        if (item.key !== uniqueKey) {
                                            item.value.scrollToOffset({
                                                offset: 0,
                                                animated: false
                                            })
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    </>
                )}
            </ScrollValueContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

So my code is like this. where flatlist wrapper is just the wrapper of flatlist.
In flatlist scroll to offset is not working properly when the no of items are less than 3. If the no of items are greater or equal to 3 than it is working exactly fine.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: ```
 setTimeout(() => {
    log('setTileout is called', this.scrolledValue > HEADER_HEIGHT)
    this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({
     offset: this.scrolledValue > HEADER_HEIGHT ? HEADER_HEIGHT : 0,
     animated: false
    })
   }, 0)
```

Comment: where HEADER_HEIGHT is 80

Comment: you can edit your question. code in comments are hard to read.

Comment: i have edited the question. If possible please give some simple explanation of scrollToOffset.

Comment: I think offset is wrong. offset is the position of item you want to scroll to. if you share enough code to reproduce list, i will create a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/) for you.

Comment: I have posted the code.Thanku for providing help

Comment: If the number of items height is greater than device height than only ScrollToOffset is working. If the flatlist height is smaller than device width then scroll to offset is not scrolling

Comment: that makes sense, isn't it?